# if statement within double for loop: specific example

Tags: r, if-statement, bioinformatics

I'm writing a short code which compares two dataframes- list & knownlocation. I want to know for each item in list, whether it falls within a knownlocation.

```
colnames(list) <- c("gene_symbol", "chromo", "start", "end")
colnames(knownlocation) <- c("snp", "chr", "s", "e")
```

To find this I wrote the code to make a new column in "list" saying TRUE or FALSE whether it's in any of knownlocation:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(list)) {
for (j in 1:nrow(knownlocation)) {
if ( (list[i, 2] == knownlocation[j, 2]) && (list[i, 3] >= knownlocation[j, 3]) && (list[i, 4] <= knownlocation[j, 4]) ) {
list[i, 5] = "TRUE" }
else { list[i, 5] = "FALSE"}
}}
```

This code looks fine to me and it runs with no errors. Problem is the entire list shows FALSE, even if it does fall within a location in knownlocation. Can anyone find something obviously wrong that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is the `else` clause will overwrite with `FALSE` on previous instances where `TRUE` was found. Basically, you only want to store `TRUE` when condition is met, but initialize all values to `FALSE` prior to execution of the loop.

Try and remove the `else` clause.

To initialize column 5 of the `list` with `FALSE` do the following right before the the nested looping:

```
list$V5 = FALSE
```

Code:

```
list$V5=TRUE
for (i in 1:nrow(list)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(knownlocation)) {
    if ( (list[i, 2] == knownlocation[j, 2]) && (list[i, 3] >= knownlocation[j, 3]) && (list[i, 4] <= knownlocation[j, 4]) ) {
      list[i, 5] = "TRUE" }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.